# symmetric matrices multiplications

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two square matrices $P$ and $Q$. Given $P = I - PQ$
I managed to show that $P$ is invertible and that $PQ = QP$.
I need to show somehow that if $Q$ is symmetric then $P$ is symmetric as well.

I have tried to develop $(I - PQ)^T$ in hopes that it will equal to $P$ but no such luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

$$P(I+Q)=I$$
Taking transpose:
$$(I+Q)P^T=I$$

Are you able to see why $P$ is symmetric?

Comment: P(I+Q) = (I+Q)P^t . But we don't know that (I+Q) is invertible and therefore we cannot just  assume that P = P^t. Still missing something. :(

Comment: I see. what is the definition of $(I+Q)$ being invertible?

Comment: ok, ok, (I+Q) is the inverse of P. But it appears to the right of P and to the left of P^t. So would it be legal to "divide" by (I+Q) on two different sides?

Comment: a more proper term is to multiply $(I+Q)^{-1}$. We can post multiply something for one equation and pre multiply something for another equation.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 Alternatively, we can use the two equalities given in this answer to say $$P = PI = P(I+Q)P^T = IP^T = P^T$$